# What are the downsides of module level state as opposed to a simple closure?

Tags: javascript, module, closures, state

I have always felt that module level states/mutable-variables are bad and ugly but I can't explain *why*. Here is an example of module I'm talking about:

```js
// module with top level state
let book = null;

export function init() {
  book = { 
    name: 'a good book', 
    author: 'me'
  }
}

export function rest() {
  book = null;
}

export function fetchBook() {
  fetch('/book').then(b => book = b)
}

export function get() {
  return book;
}
```

vs

```js
// module with closure
export default function() {
  let book = null;
  return {
    init: () => { /* same as module */ },
    reset: () => { /* same as module */ },
    fetchBook: () => { /* same as module */ },
    get: () => { /* same as module */ }
  }
}
```

The only difference I can see is since the module is resolved once, the module level state is similar to "singleton" but the closure one can be instantiated multiple time and they have their own version of the state. What are other cons/pros of the module level states?

Comment: pro: readability. static analysis of dependencies (-> bundling, better tooling, ...). cons: none that I know of?

Comment: @JonasWilms, module or closure?

Comment: "*the module is a "singleton" but the closure one can be instantiated multiple times*" - that's all you need to know, no? The difference is large enough that other factors do not matter for deciding between the two.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah but there are differences when testing for example. I can change the closure to accept a mock book as input to facilitate the testing. You can't pass arguments to a module import.

Comment: @norbert Exactly, and that's the reason why you should choose the closure if you want to test with mocks.

Answer (score 1):

### commonJS

When using commonJS or any bundler (webpack/rollup), modules are executed by encapsulating them into a closure, passing `require`, `module`, etc as parameters and executing this function ones (caching for every `require`). So in the end, it comes down to the same. So whether to use module variables comes down to a question of personal preference, at least with commonJS.

(See nodejs implementation for loading cjs modules [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L197))

### ES Modules

ES Modules bring braking changes to the table:

```js
// module.mjs

export let string = "not done";

setTimeout(() => {
    res("done");
}, 1000);


// main.mjs

import { string } from "./module.mjs";

console.log(string); // "not done"

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(string); // "done"
}, 2000);
```

Named ES Module exports can be reassigned by **exporting** module. This makes modules behave more like objects than closures. Whether this is a good or a bad thing, you have to decide for yourself.

#### warning

Using `import`/`export` **does not** mean that you are using ES Modules! Babel Modules and Typescript use the same import/export syntax but under the hood transpile to commonJS. You can run the ES Modules example from above with Typescript or Babel and will get different results from running it with nodejs with ES Modules enabled.

#### My 2 cents

Use module variables only if you know what you are doing and are aware of the implications. It's like with equality vs strict equality.

Comment: "*Named ES Module exports can be reassigned by importing modules*" - no, they cannot. Your example throws an exception in any compliant environment.

Comment: "*Using `import`/`export` does not mean that you are using ES Modules!*" - huh?

Comment: @Bergi You are right, I made a mistake. Only the exporting module can change the imported variable. I also clarified my statement about the import/export syntax.